# How to integrate urbanAirship

Tags: urbanairship.com

How can we integrate the UrbanAirship to our server. I want to send push information through my server, without going into urbanAirship.

Whatever information is sent through my sever, has to send via urbanAirship. If it's possible please guide me how can I to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want more control and run the service along side your server without going to a third party like UrbanAirship, you can try OpenMobster Mobile Cloud platform's push service: http://openmobster.googlecode.com

It provides the following functionality

A platform agnostic Push API (works on Android and iOS)

Queuing (If you are not available, it will deliver later when the phone comes online)

Should get you up and running quite fast. (No certificates, device tokens etc etc). Just a secure persistent TCP connection to the OpenMobster server is needed (the framework establishes this when the service is installed on the phone)

For more on the platform you can checkout: http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/PushFramework

btw: The platform also supports Device-To-Device messaging between other devices in the systsem (applications could be chat, instant messaging etc)

D2D Framework doc: http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/D2DPushFramework

Comment: Thank you, ill do study on OpenMobster .!!